# Loading spinner not showing in React Component

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

I am creating a React.js app which got 2 components - The main one is a container for the 2nd and is responsible for retrieving the information from a web api and then pass it to the child component which is responsible for displaying the info in a list of items. The displaying component is supposed to present a loading spinner while waiting for the data items from the parent component.

The problem is that when the app is loaded, I first get an empty list of items and then all of a sudden all the info is loaded to the list, without the spinner ever showing. I get a filter first in one of the `useEffects` and based on that info, I am bringing the items themselves.

The parent is doing something like this:

```
useEffect(() =>
{
    async function getNames()
    {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const names = await WebAPI.getNames();
        setAllNames(names);
        setSelectedName(names[0]);
        setIsLoading(false);
    };
    getNames();
  } ,[]);

  useEffect(() =>
  {
    async function getItems()
    { 
        setIsLoading(true);
        const items= await WebAPI.getItems(selectedName);
        setAllItems(items);
        setIsLoading(false);
    };
    getTenants();
  },[selectedName]);

  .
  .
  .
  return (
     <DisplayItems items={allItems} isLoading={isLoading} />
   );
```

And the child components is doing something like this:

```
let spinner = props.isLoading ? <Spinner className="SpinnerStyle" /> : null; //please assume no issues in Spinner component
let items = props.items;
return (
   {spinner}
   {items}
)
```

I'm guessing that the problem is that the `setEffect` is asynchronous which is why the component is first loaded with `isLoading` false and then the entire action of `setEffect` is invoked before actually changing the state? Since I do assume here that I first set the `isLoading` and then there's a rerender and then we continue to the rest of the code on useEffect. I'm not sure how to do it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the asynchronicity when using mulitple useEffect. What I did to solve the issue was adding another spinner for the filters values I mentioned, and then the `useEffect` responsible for retrieving the values set is loading for that specific spinner, while the other for retrieving the items themselves set the isLoading for the main spinner of the items.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing it like you are I would slightly tweak it:

remove `setIsLoading(true);` from below

```
useEffect(() =>
{
    async function getNames()
    {
        setIsLoading(true); //REMOVE THIS LINE
        const names = await WebAPI.getNames();
        setAllNames(names);
        setSelectedName(names[0]);
        setIsLoading(false);
    };
    getNames();
  } ,[]);
```

and have `isLoading` set to `true` in your initial state. that way, it's always going to show loading until you explicitly tell it not to. i.e. when you have got your data

also change the rendering to this:

```
let items = props.items;
return isLoading ? (
   <Spinner className="SpinnerStyle" />
) : <div> {items} </div>
```

Comment: It's actually already true in the initial state and I just set it again to true at the beginning of every action

Comment: but if the spinner is true, how are you not seeing the spinner? are you sure this is true? `props.isLoading`  also I've changed how you should show the spinner in my code

Comment: @YonatanNir try rendering like this instead

Comment: I tried now and when I'm debugging I can see the spinner until the first useEffect ends with setIsLoading(false), but it seems like other useEffect already passed the point of setIsLoading(true) so no one else is turning it back on

Comment: did you try the different rendering? did it have effect?

Comment: The issue is with the asynchronicity. All the setLoading(true) are called first and after that all the setLoading(false), while what I want is them to be paired true false

Comment: @YonatanNir are you wanting to set the loading spinner for the whole page or for each segment? you could try chaining the async calls. I don't really see a problem with it being async. you simply show a loading spinner, make the request, once request fulfills, unset loading spinner. problem might be you setting it in 4 place, either combine them into 1 useeffect. or only setLoading once.

Comment: I want to be able to set the spinner to show before the first operation of setEffect and turn it off after the last one. I thought that all useEffects run one after another but it doesn't seem to be the case

Answer (score 0):

this is full example with loading :

```js
const fakeApi = (name) =>
  new Promise((resolve)=> {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([{ name: "Mike", id: 1 }, { name: "James", id: 2 }].filter(item=>item.name===name));
    }, 3000);
  })
  
  const getName =()=>   new Promise((resolve)=> {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Mike");
    }, 3000);
  })
const Parent = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState();
   const [data, setData] = React.useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const fetchData =(name) =>{
    if(!loading) setLoading(true);
      fakeApi(name).then(res=>
      setData(res)
      )
      }
    const fetchName = ()=>{
    setLoading(true);
    getName().then(res=> setName(res))
    }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchName();
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
   if(name)fetchData(name);
  }, [name]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
  if(data && loading) setLoading(false)
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <div>
      {loading
        ? "Loading..."
        : data && data.map((d)=>(<Child key={d.id} {...d} />))}
    </div>
  );
};
const Child = ({ name,id }) =>(<div>{name}  {id}</div>)

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>,document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: The issue is with the asynchronicity when using mulitple useEffect. All the setLoading(true) are called first and after that all the setLoading(false), while what I want is them to be paired true false

Comment: so what are you trying to do is to have same loading for both async action ??